# Why do we normalize the fft power by sampling rate and number of data points to find the PSD?

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

When finding the power spectrum density (PSD) from the $N$-FFT of time-domain signal $x(t)$ of $N$ data points (assuming $N=2^n$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$), we normalize the power of the FFT by the sampling rate $f_s$ times the number of data points $N$ like so

$$S[i]=\frac{2|X[i]|^2}{f_s\times N},\,\,\,i=0,\frac{fs}{N},\frac{2f_s}{N},\cdots,\frac{fs}{2}$$

where $S[i]$ and $X[i]$ are the PSD and FFT at frequency bin $i$.

I understand the scaling factor 2 since we need preserve the total energy after removing the negative spectrum, but I don't understand the scaling $\frac{1}{f_s N}$.

Also, the scaling $1/N$ happens as I understand when we use rectangular pulse shaping. What happens if we use root raise cosine filtering where each pulse spans $L$ symbols, for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/80812/1629

Comment: Or [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/27213/4298)?

Comment: Or, in my opinion the best resource on the subject: [this](https://holometer.fnal.gov/GH_FFT.pdf)

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I have better understanding now, but still struggling to understand the normalized power per bin $$\left(|X[i]|/N\right)^2$$. Why do we normalize the magnitude by $N$ before finding the power?